# NetLogo: How to build using the "with" syntax in the "ifelse" syntax with specific conditions?

Tags: netlogo

How can I build a syntax for an "ifelse" statement that has a turtle in a specified patch and has the turtle determine if the turtle's color is the specified color? The following is sample code, but it won't work. Incidentally, I would like to build it using "max-pxcor - 1".

```
ifelse count turtles-on patch (max-pxcor - 1) with [color = red] = 1[ ;The following code is omitted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) The patch X Y notation selects a specific patch but you have not provided a `pycor`. I assume you therefore want any patch with the correct value for `pxcor`. How many of those patches are coloured red? (2) If you are not selecting a patch with its identifier, then you are working with a patchset rather than a patch, even if there is only one patch in that set. If you need to get a patch from a patchset, you need `one-of`.

If you actually want to identify that patch so you can do something with it, then this approach separates the patches from the turtles so is reasonably readable:

```
let wanted-patch one-of patches with [pxcor = max-pxcor - 1 and color = red]
ifelse count turtles-on wanted-patch = 1
[
```

But you could also do:

```
ifelse any? patches with [pxcor = max-pxcor - 1 and
                          color = red and
                          count turtles-here = 1]
[
```

Of, if you genuinely want the patchset so the total number of turtles on all the right hand column red patches is 1 (so 1 on one patch and 0 on others), then:

```
ifelse count (turtles-on patches with [pxcor = max-pxcor - 1 and color = red]) = 1
[
```

For this last one, the () are optional, for readability.